# Selenium: Using a Chrome Profile for Remote Webdriver: unknown error: cannot create default profile directory

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-remotedriver, chrome-profile

Using ChromeDriver v102 (since there's a current bug open for v103 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4121)

I get the error (full log information listed below):

```
Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot create default profile directory
```

when I run ChromeDriver remotely on the selenium node grid.

I am able to use a specific chrome profile when running the ChromeDriver locally. The driver for Firefox also works remotely, so I have to conclude that this is a "remote ChromeDriver" issue.

I download the chrome profile from the cloud into my current working directory. The directory is detected/located in my code.

There are no spaces in my path to the profile directory. The chrome profile only contains essential files I want to keep.

```
save_file_list = ["Bookmarks", "History", "History-journal", "Cookies", "Cookies-Journal", "Favicons", "Favicons-journal"]
```

When I use the ChromeDriver locally, I download the chrome profile, it loads the essential files and the driver creates the rest on its own. The same code works (and runs in an executable) when I run it on windows and mac machines.

However, this fails to work at all when using the remote driver. The remote driver works perfectly when I do not use a specific user-data-dir. It even works using an authenticated proxy. Therefore there are no issues with my connection. The code fails in both cases: when I use a virtual environment to run the code and when I run a docker image. Therefore I know it's not a docker issue.

This is the code for loading a chrome profile to my chrome options:

```
def add_profile(self, chrome_options):
        if self.download_profile():
            arg = f'--user-data-dir={os.getcwd()}/{self.profile_path}'
            logging.info(f'Adding arg: {arg}')
            chrome_options.add_argument(arg)
            logging.info("Successfully added profile to chrome driver.")
        return chrome_options



def setup_chrome(self) -> webdriver.Remote:
        prefs = {
            "credentials_enable_service": False,
            "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
        }

        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        chrome_options = self.proxy.add_proxy_plugin(chrome_options, use_proxy=True)
        
        chrome_options = self.chrome_profile.add_profile(chrome_options) #currently not working

        capabilities = {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "chromeOptions": {
                "useAutomationExtension": False,
                "forceDevToolsScreenshot": True,
                "args": ["--start-maximized", "--disable-infobars"],
            },
        }

        remote_driver_host = os.environ.get("SELENIUM_URL")
        logging.info("Setting up remote connection")
        try:
            selenium_connection = RemoteConnectionV2(
                remote_driver_host, keep_alive=False
            )
            selenium_connection.set_remote_connection_authentication_headers()

            driver = webdriver.Remote(
                command_executor=selenium_connection,  # for prod
                # command_executor="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", # for local development
                desired_capabilities=capabilities,
                options=chrome_options,
                keep_alive=True,
            )

            logging.info("SUCCESS: created remote chrome using connection")
        except Exception as ex:
            logging.error(f"Failed to initiate Chrome browser: {ex}")
            raise

        try:
            driver.get("https://www.google.com")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Failed to connect using proxy: {e}")

        return driver
```

This is the log:

```
27-Jun-22 10:04:53 AM EDT | INFO | SUCCESS: downloaded proxy assignment:
27-Jun-22 10:04:54 AM EDT | INFO | Successfully downloaded & extracted _zGF_23_CHROME_PROFILE.
27-Jun-22 10:04:54 AM EDT | INFO | Adding arg: --user-data-dir=/Users/<myuser>/Repos<my-repo>/_zGF_23_CHROME_PROFILE
27-Jun-22 10:04:54 AM EDT | INFO | Successfully added profile to chrome driver.
27-Jun-22 10:04:54 AM EDT | INFO | Setting up remote connection
[Authentication] No identity token was found in the environment. Requesting a new one.
[Authentication] An identity token found successfully.
27-Jun-22 10:04:55 AM EDT | ERROR | Failed to initiate Chrome browser: Message: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot create default profile directory
Build info: version: '4.2.2', revision: '683ccb65d6'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.2.2', revision: '683ccb65d6'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Stacktrace:
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply (DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:194)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply (DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.SessionSlot.apply (SessionSlot.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode.newSession (LocalNode.java:362)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.startSession (LocalDistributor.java:618)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.newSession (LocalDistributor.java:544)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.handleNewSessionRequest (LocalDistributor.java:791)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.lambda$run$1 (LocalDistributor.java:752)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:829)
27-Jun-22 10:04:55 AM EDT | ERROR | Message: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot create default profile directory
Build info: version: '4.2.2', revision: '683ccb65d6'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.2.2', revision: '683ccb65d6'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Stacktrace:
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply (DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:194)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply (DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.SessionSlot.apply (SessionSlot.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode.newSession (LocalNode.java:362)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.startSession (LocalDistributor.java:618)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor.newSession (LocalDistributor.java:544)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.handleNewSessionRequest (LocalDistributor.java:791)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.distributor.local.LocalDistributor$NewSessionRunnable.lambda$run$1 (LocalDistributor.java:752)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: check the path... make sure it's absolute and that it exists on the remote machine...  BTW, that bug you linked to goes back to v99 methinks... but I think it's actually a bug in Chrome's Dev Tools Protocol.  (the browser)

Comment: I didn’t think the profile had to exist in the remote machine. I believe it’s suppose to exist in the same machine where the driver is being called.

Comment: I think you said you were using a remote driver... so your local webdriver is making calls to your grid which is on the remote machine.  That remote driver is then making calls to the remote browser.

Comment: So if I'm unable to download the chrome profile on the remote machine, running my selenium grid, then I can't use a chrome profile? Is that right?

Comment: By default it'll create a temporary profile to use.  You can create a profile on the remote machine and use that if you like... just make sure the path is set correctly.